# ( Hp 840 g3 i5 Gen 6) Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS first time installation of KDE-full is stuck on tty login

Tags: kde, plasma

Hello can anyone explain if it's possible to refresh your Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS from the grub shell option. OR if there's a solution to revert the settings on boot up? I installed kde-full on top of it now it's stuck on the tty cli and I have tried almost everything I could find on the internet. It's my daily machine I need a fix ASAP.

Comment: Grub is a *boot loader* and runs before the Linux kernel or your main Ubuntu system has booted; but upgrading packages is a Ubuntu function and requires Ubuntu be running for it to work.  You can add other desktops to an existing Ubuntu system, but how you do it can vary on release unless you install everything via large metapackage. We can't help about your actual problem unless we're told about it (ie. adding `kubuntu-desktop` to a Ubuntu system will work as long as you've sufficient disk space etc) FYI:  This is a Q&A site & not a forum.

Comment: @guiverc thank you for your insights and reply. Maybe I didn't explain the problem well enough. I installed kubuntu-desktop fine on my previously loading Ubuntu GNOME-environment. The problem started when I rebooted my machine it could pass the login info phase. So I tried ctrl + alt + f3 to get to the Ubuntu shell but then it's not letting me login in. What could be the problem?

Comment: In your question you mention [`kde-full`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kde-full) but your your last comment you mention [`kubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/kubuntu-desktop) which is a different package.. Please be precise with details as they do matter (`kubuntu-desktop` should work on all releases for example as it contains everything Kubuntu provide). Could you use a terminal login before? (ie. language differences handled by a DM that you may have changed?)  I'd also boot *live* & check you have space (in $HOME etc) as required for GUI login (not text though?)

Comment: I'm sort of new to this pardon my confusion yes I installed kde-full and changed the configuration to ssdm, while I only wanted wanted the plasma desktop on my Ubuntu. I have enough space for GUI login. I will try and live boot and check whether it solves the problem. I have never tried terminal login before cause it has always been working fine with the GUI.

Comment: *live* booting will do nothing, it's just what I'd use to confirm you have free space. The Kubuntu team ensure `kubuntu-desktop` works as it is what is included on their ISOs, for less than complete packages (eg. `kde-full`) a lot of what's there comes from upstream Debian with only minor changes by Kubuntu/Ubuntu that are tested with everything else too. Your prior default was `gdm3` as for DM which uses GNOME/GTK calls (& configs) for many things so language maybe an issue here IF you're not using US layout & EN as language, but that's guess (I'm aussie & US keybd is what we use...)

Comment: @guiverc I use the English, american keyboard layout and yes my prior was gdm3 I switched to ssdm when prompted.